# Join multiple conditions using Where method in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to join two different conditions on an **Active Record** Database.
Usually, I'll join them using a comma (`,`) or `AND`, but in this case, putting a comma or AND between conditions returns an error.

I wonder how to join those conditions together in one statement (I'm using rails 4):

```
MyTable.where("created_at < ?", Time.now - 86400) # 86400 represent a day

MyTable.where(my_column: my_variable)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyTable.where("created_at < ? AND my_column = ?", Time.now - 86400, my_variable)
```

Comment: There's also `MyTable.where(...).where(...)` if separating the conditions is easier to read.